# svm KKT condition violation that alpha choice in SMO

Tags: svm

when I was read the paper about SMO　for SVM.
[John C. Platt paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr-98-14.pdf)

choosing the alpha which violated KKT condition is very confusing me. I do not very understand the code as below.

```
if ((r2 < -tol && alph2 < C) || (r2 > tol && alph2 > 0))
```

why does it choose r2 < -tol when alph2 < C, not r2 < tol?

Answer (score 0):

#### Defining Importance of KKT Conditions

First, note that the KKT conditions for SVM are especially helpful for getting rid of vectors that are not the support vectors. With that, consider a (non-support) vector point for example with label 1 that is far above the hyperplane (correctly identified). Consider that if you plug the point into decision equation, you will likely get a value like 2.5, because that point is not a support vector. Points like that are systematically weeded out during the optimization phase of SVM so that the only points with weighted value are support vectors close to the hyperplane.

#### Given: The KKT conditions are violated when:

- [a_i < C and y_i (+b) < 1], or
- [a_i > 0 and y_i (+b) > 1]

Now let's look at the pseudocode you mentioned from Platt.

#### Pseudocode Excerpt from Plat 1998:

```
E2 = SVM output on point[i2] – y2 (check in error cache)
r2 = E2*y2

if ((r2 < -tol && alph2 < C) || (r2 > tol && alph2 > 0))
```

#### Platt's Paper and the KKT Conditions

Given the values of r2 and E2,  Platt's if-statement says the following mathematically:

if [y_i ((w,x) + b - y_i) < -tol && alpha2 < C] or [y_i ((w,x) + b - y_i) > tol && alpha2 > 0]

Let's set tol to 0. The equation of the first condition now reads:
y_i ((w,x) + b - y_i) < 0

Rewritten, this is essentially:
y_i ((w,x) + b) < 1, since (y_i)*(y_i) will always be positive 1. The condition:
[y_i ((w,x) + b) < 1 and a < C] exactly matches our definition of what violates the KKT conditions. If you view the other condition, it will also exactly match the other KKT violation.

What this code means, going further, is that here Platt is checking for ("non-border") violators of the KKT conditions. He's essentially trying to weed out those points that are obviously not close to the hyperplane at all.